# German equivalent to "going down the rabbit hole"

Tags: english-to-german, idiom

Was ist eine passende Übersetzung für die Redewendung "going down the rabbit hole"?

Im Sinne von: man informiert sich über Thema X, stößt dann auf Wikipedia auf das zusammenhängende Thema Y, von da zum Thema Z und auf einmal ist es 2 Uhr nachts.

#### Edit:

Ich kann anscheinend keine Kommentare verfassen, daher hier nochmal eine Klarstellung:

@Pollitzer tut mir leid, wenn meine Frage inkonsistent sein sollte. Ich meinte es aber tatsächlich so wie @tofro - sich in etwas einarbeiten, dabei ständig neue Facetten aufzudecken und so immer tiefer in das Thema einzudringen. Ein konkretes Beispiel, woher auch meine Frage stammt:

Ich informiere mich über Domain-Registrierung, komme dann über Wikipedia auf die ICANN, dann irgendwie auf Webhosting, dedizierte Server, Root-Server, statisches Webhosting (gh pages, netlify, zeit), statische Websitegeneratoren (jekyll, gatsby), …

Eigentlich wollte ich nur etwas über Domains erfahren.

#### Edit 2:

Ich bin deutscher Muttersprachler. Kann gut sein, dass ich schon die englische Redewendung falsch verstanden habe. Sie ist relativ häufig auf Reddit zu finden. Zum Beispiel [in diesem Post](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/6h57ce/what_is_the_most_puzzling_or_interesting_rabbit/) oder auch [hier](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/bdfmnf/what_are_some_good_internet_rabbitholes_to_check/).

Comment: Der Kontext ist ein bisschen dünn, vielleicht passt *sich verzetteln*?

Comment: Vielleicht auch "etwas zieht einen Rattenschwanz hinterher"

Comment: Bist du denn ein Englisch-Erstsprachler oder sonstwie sicher, dass du *going down the rabbit hole* hier richtig (oder jedenfalls typisch) verwendest? Oder sprechen wir hier über eine möglicherweise seltene Nebenbedeutung des Ausdrucks?

Comment: Die Bedeutung, die du für die originale englische Wendung verstanden hast, ist *eine der möglichen*. Wenn man sich verinnerlicht, dass die Wendung sich auf "Alice im Wunderland" bezieht, ist ein anderes Extrem, dass sie z.B. "Eintauchen in eine zauberhafte Wunderwelt" bedeutet.

Comment: Ich begegne der Karnickelhöhlenmetapher auch sehr oft besonders bei US-amerikanischen Zuschriften. Ich finde es dort aber überwiegend in einem Kontext, der nahelegt, dass es als "in eine Sache hineingeraten und nicht mehr rauskommen" (kurz: sich verstricken) gemeint ist.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann "nicht mehr rauskommen" ist nicht Teil der Bedeutung. "verstricken" auch nicht unbedingt, "sich eingraben" schon eher

Comment: Merriam-Webster has an [entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rabbit%20hole) for *rabbit hole.* The term is from Lewis Carroll's *Alice in Wonderland.* The metaphor indeed involves spending substantial time, losing orientation, being stuck somewhere with no easy way out, finding a previously unknown, surreal realm full of weird things which existed all the time not far from home.

Comment: So, ungefähr : https://xkcd.com/761/ ?

Comment: @EricDuminil or https://xkcd.com/609/

Comment: @Holger jop, die passen beide wie die Faust aufs Auge.

Comment: Als Anmerkung zum Edit bereits gepostet, aber da wird es leicht übersehen: Keine Danksagung in Kommentaren oder Beitrag, bitte. Werte gute Antworten auf, indem Du die Pfeile nach oben anklickst. Die beste kannst Du mit dem Haken auszeichnen.

Comment: Die Frage ist irreführend. Wie man einen Wikipedia-Marathon sonst noch bezeichnet ist relativ subjektiv und vom Zuhörer abhängig. *down the rabbit whole* ist nicht spezifisch für Wikipedia oder das Lesen an sich. Dementsprechend haben die Antworten auch wenig mit dem englischen Idiom zu tun, das schon mehrfach in's Deutsche übersetzt wurde, etwa in Matrix. Eine komplett parallele Konstruktion hat sich meines Wissens nicht verfestigt. ggf zählt auf deutsch *in den Fuchsbau*, *in die Tiefen des Karnickelbaus* o.ä.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

*Going down the rabbit hole* in dem Sinn, wie es in der Frage vorgestellt wurde, nämlich als thematische Verzettelung, lässt sich im Deutschen ausdrücken als

> vom Hölzchen aufs Stöckchen kommen

Diese Wendung ist mindestens im südlichen Teil des deutschen Sprachraums bekannt. (Kommentatoren unten bestätigen aber das Vorkommen auch für andere Regionen.)

Natürlich könnte man, wie es ja gerade schon passiert ist, auch sagen:

> sich verzetteln

Jedoch: Lesen wir *going down the rabbit hole* hier überhaupt richtig? Ich hatte diesen Ausdruck bisher immer etwas anders verstanden, nämlich entweder als

> sich [in ein Thema] vertiefen
>
> ins Detail gehen
>
> sich hineinfuchsen

was eine Konzentration auf ein Thema meint, die positiv gesehen wird; oder aber - und dies durchaus am häufigsten - als etwas Negatives oder geradezu Gefährliches wie

> sich verstricken
>
> in eine Sache immer tiefer hineingeraten
>
> aus einer Sache nicht mehr herauskommen

Vielleicht müsste man erst klären, was mit *going down the rabbit hole* wirklich - oder am typischsten - gemeint ist.

Comment: "vom Hölzchen aufs Stöckchen kommen" muss sehr regional sein, ich habe sie noch nie gehört oder gelesen.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf Denke ich auch, allerdings finde ich es sehr passend! :)

Comment: Es gibt auch noch "vom Hundertsten ins Tausendste kommen", vielleicht wäre das bekannt. Ansonsten gäb's noch allgemeinere Redensarten wie 'ich kam da (wieder / wie immer) an kein Ende', war 'nicht mehr zu bremsen' oder 'ich konnte die Stoptaste nicht finden' oder 'dann hat's mich wieder geritten und'...

Comment: "vom Hölzchen aufs Stöckchen kommen" kam mir auch als erstes in den Sinn.

Comment: Als Referenz aus dem Ruhrgebiet, Hölzchen aufs Stöckchen ist mir sehr wohl bekannt. Aber vom Hundetstens ins Tausendste kommen ist mir vollkomen unbekannt.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf als Berliner kenne ich sie auch. Bezieht sich allerdings mehr auf einen Redner, der immer mehr abschweift, nicht auf eigene Recherche. Siehe auch https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/vom_H%C3%B6lzchen_aufs_St%C3%B6ckchen_kommen Wenn man dagegen die Tiefen des Kaninchenbaus im gleichen Sinne wie im Englischen meint, ist die Redewendung als wörtliche Übersetzung durchaus bekannt, Alice im Wunderland wurde ja auch ins Deutsche übersetzt. In Matrix hat man sie z.B. auch wörtlich übersetzt.

Comment: vom Hölzchen aufs Stöckchen ist mittlerweile von Christian als im Süden, vonKami Kaze im Ruhrpott, und hiermit von mir für Norddeutschland belegt - so regional kann es demnach nicht sein. Allerdings halte ich es nicht für eine 100% gute Entsprechung zu going down the rabbit hole ...

Comment: Vom Hölzchen aufs Stöckchen ist auch im hessischen Sprachraum bekannt.

Answer (score 25):

Für das von dir beschriebene Abschweifen/Abkommen vom eigentlichen Thema gibt es die Redewendung

> [vom Hundertsten ins Tausendste kommen](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=vom%20Hundertsten&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_varianten_ou)

Comment: Daran hatte ich auch schon gedacht, aber diese Redewendung kenne ich eigentlich nur im Zusammenhang mit (in erster Linie mündlichem) Erzählen. Also wenn derjenige, der etwas erzählt, dabei abschweift und insbesondere immer mehr in unwichtige Details abgleitet.

Comment: "going down the rabbit hole" hat eigentlich nichts mit "abschweifen" zu tun, sondern eher mit dem genauen Gegenteil - also konzentriertes, intensives Einarbeiten in ein Thema.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf: Das dürfe auch nach meiner Einschätzung die häufigste Verwendung sein.

Comment: @tofro: Die Frage scheint inkonsistent gestellt zu sein, ich halte mich bei meiner Antwort an _»Im Sinne von:«_.

Comment: To "go down a rabbit hole" is to explore the depths of something that on the surface may appear simple. You may be surprised to discover the subject *is* a so-called "rabbit hole", deeper than expected.  It *doesn't* mean to digress, to ramble, to dilute focus, to explore too many subjects, etc. It means the opposite: to hyper focus, to going maximally deep into *one* subject*, to *not* lose the thread, to steadfastly *not* depart from the original topic, to do a so-called "deep dive" on a subject. That's somewhat the opposite of "vom Hundertsten ins Tausendste kommen".

Comment: @Mud: Thanks for your clarification, I came to _»vom Hundertsten ins Tausendste kommen«_ since the OP is talking of going over from one topic to another.

Comment: Ein Kaninchenbau ist aber weniger durch Tiefe, als durch Verästelung gekennzeichnet. Vom 100sten ins Tausendste kommen spiegelt das wieder. Findet der Fuchs das Kaninchen nicht im ersten Gang muss er in den zweiten, der sich womöglich weiter aufspaltet.

Answer (score 17):

Given that the expression is from *Alice in Wonderland,* where Alice gets lost in this parallel reality, I would opt for **sich in etwas verlieren:**

> Eigentlich wollte ich nur etwas über Domains erfahren, aber dann verlor ich mich irgendwo zwischen Webhosting und statischen Seitengeneratoren.

Comment: Finde ich auch sehr passend, danke!

Comment: My pleasure. It's an interesting question; words or phrases which do not have an exact equivalent in the other language often show differences in culture (have you ever tried to translate *Feierabend?*). Another example which comes to mind, also literature-based, is [Serendipity](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/serendipity).

Answer (score 13):

Um in der Tierwelt zu bleiben:

> sich in etwas reinfuchsen

verwendet fast dasselbe Bild, nur mit Fuchs statt Kaninchen und ist auch ähnlich in der Umgangssprache verortet wie "going down the rabbit hole"

Comment: Konnotation ist aber in meinen Augen nicht dieselbe: sich in etwas reinfuchsen = etwas lernen; going down the rabbit hole = bei etwas festhängen.

Comment: @TemporaryName "sich in etwas reinfuchsen" ist mMn definitiv nicht "etwas lernen", sondern "sich extrem intensiv mit etwas auseinandersetzen, bis man es volllkommen durchdrungen hat" (und dabei wird man schonmal "festhängen" - auch wenn "an etwas festhängen" auch nicht die Bedeutung von "down a rabbit hole" hat)

Comment: Schau dir die Bedeutung von "going down the rabbit hole" mal an: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/going-down-the-rabbit-hole, auch wenn "sich in etwas reinfuchsen" nicht direkt lernen ist, hat es eine andere Bedeutung als "going down the rabbit hole".

Comment: @TemporaryName Der Link ist *eine* mögliche (wahrscheinlich die ursprünglichste) Bedeutung. Ich glaube nicht die, auf die sich die Frage bezieht. Ich begegne der Wendung immer wieder, wenn sich jemand z.B. durch komplizierte Technik oder Dokumente "durchgegraben" hat.

Comment: Stimmt. Hab die Edits nicht gelesen. Die Konnotation ist aber, mMn, eben nicht so positiv. Kommt soweit ich das weiß auch von Alice im Wunderland. Die lernt ja auch nicht, sondern verirrt sich eher.

Comment: Wurde auch in den Kommentaren im OP erklärt. Sorry.

Answer (score 9):

Sich in etwas verrennen.

... war meine unmittelbare Assoziation.

Comment: Sehr schön, ja.

Comment: "Sich in etwas verrennen" hat für mich aber eine sehr negative Konnotation, so in Richtung Querulant/Unbelehrbarer, also eher jemand, der beharrlich versucht, sich nur passende Information zu besorgen und nicht so sehr jemanden, der vom Thema abschweift.

Comment: Passt für mein Verständnis allerdings zum sprichwörtlichen Rabbit Hole - damit ist meines Wissens nach auch kein einfaches Abschweifen gemeint, und die Konnotation ist oft (leicht) negativ, impliziert eine gewisse Zeitverschwendung.

Answer (score 4):

Neben dem schon von @guidot im Kommentar vorgeschlagenen *sich verzetteln* käme da noch *sich festlesen* in Frage.
Ansonsten würde man das eher mit längeren Formulierungen wie *beim Lesen tief eingetaucht und dabei die Zeit vergessen* oder so ähnlich ausdrücken.

Edit:
Nach den Edits an der Fragestellung möchte ich noch hinzufügen, dass die Wahl der Formulierung tatsächlich davon abhängt, ob es sich darum handelt, dass man beim Lesen auf weiterführende Informationen gestoßen ist, die man zum Verständnis benötigt, also schlichtweg für die Recherche viel mehr Zeit als erwartet gebraucht hat (da passt dann das *reinfuchsen* oder *ins Detail gehen* aus den anderen Antworten), oder ob man auf Informationen gestoßen ist, die *zwar interessant, aber nicht notwendig* sind und **damit** Zeit verbraten hat (da sind dann eher die obigen Vorschläge passend).

Answer (score 3):

Da in der englischen Sprache Redewendungen und Sprüche oft recht inflationär verwendet werden, würde ich mich in den meisten Fällen auf bereits erwähnte Begriffe wie eintauchen, vertiefen oder verlieren beschränken.

Nachdem die Geschichte "Alice im Wunderland" auch im deutschsprachigen Raum recht bekannt ist und durch den Film Matrix zusätzlich wieder in Erinnerung gerufen wurde, kann man in einzelnen Fällen einfach den übersetzten Begriff verwenden.

> Nach dem Import meines neuen Autos musste ich mich in den
>   bürokratischen Kaninchenbau von technischen Prüfungen und Zulassungen
>   begeben.

Comment: Ich bin sehr sicher, diese Verwendung von Kaninchenbau schon häufiger im Deutschen gelesen zu haben.

Answer (score 1):

*Es hat mir den Ärmel rein gezogen/genommen.*

Das ist aber eventuell auch etwas regional. Bildlich verstehe ich das so, dass eine Maschine den Ärmel erwischt und man ganz reingezogen wird.

Comment: Interesting. Never heard that but it is a nice metaphor in the industrial age ;-).

Answer (score 1):

I had no idea that this would be such a popular topic. Please see [References from Linguee.com](https://www.linguee.com/english-german/translation/going+down+the+rabbit+hole.html).

My favorite untranslatable German idiomatic expression is "quer durch den Garten"

Answer (score 0):

Mir begegnet das oft in Meetings wenn die Gruppe vom eigentlichen Thema abkommt.

Daher meine Antwort:

> vom eigentlichen Thema abkommen

Answer (score 0):

Für mich ist "going down the rabbit hole" eine Situation, in der man selber nicht weiß, was auf einen zukommt. Ein Beispiel ist in einer Ehe, wo ein Partner fremdgeht und versteht nicht, warum das ein Problem ist. "He's gone down the rabbit hole" in eine Situation, wo er nicht versteht, welche Rolle er gespielt hat. Leider kenne ich kein passendes deutsches Sprichwort, da, wie oben erwähnt, diese Redewendung von Lewis Carrolls "Alice in Wonderland" stammt. Ich würde wetten, jeder Amerikaner/jede Amerikanerin kennt dieses Sprichwort, ohne umbedingt zu wissen, woher es kommt.